# Can not load avro by packaging spark-avro_2.11 in jar

Tags: apache-spark, avro

I use spark-submit to run a scala jar, it raise an error:

**Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".;**

the dependency is

```
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.4.4</version>
```

it seems the avro dependency does not work.

But if I add --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4 in spark-submit command, it can work.

---

the complete pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cn.com.cig.gaetl</groupId>
    <artifactId>gaetl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
        <spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.8.5</hadoop.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--hadoop-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--hadoop-aws-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--hadoop-aws-dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-paranamer</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--scala-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--spark-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-target:jvm-1.7</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <!--<repositories>-->
    <!--<repository>-->
    <!--<id>nexus-aliyun</id>-->
    <!--<name>Nexus aliyun</name>-->
    <!--<url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>-->
    <!--</repository>-->
    <!--</repositories>-->
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml files ? are you building fat jar ? I am thinking avro jar is not included in your final jar file & also can you unzip your final jar & check avro jar is available or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Because `org.apache.spark.spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4.jar` jar file is not available in class path. try building fat jar which should contain all required spark-avro dependencies.

Also check if your cluster is having lower version of spark & avro version it might not work as expected.

Try adding below code to your pom.xml & change main class in this -  `<Main-Class>...</Main-Class>`

```
<executions>
   <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
         <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
         <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
               <manifestEntries>
                  <Main-Class>...</Main-Class> 
                  <X-Compile-Source-JDK>${maven.compile.source}</X-Compile-Source-JDK>
                  <X-Compile-Target-JDK>${maven.compile.target}</X-Compile-Target-JDK>
               </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
               <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister</resource>
            </transformer>
         </transformers>
      </configuration>
   </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Hi, I pasted the complete pom.xml, how to check if it is fat jar?  the size of jar is more than 100MB

Comment: ok, unzip to some tmp location & check if spark-avro jar is available or not ?

Comment: I unzip the jar file and searched "avro", got several resulsts  `./META-INF/maven/org.apache.avro/avro     
./org/apache/spark/sql/avro     
./org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/avro     
./org/apache/avro     
./avro`

Comment: can you post what value is there inside META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.source.DataSourceRegister file ?

Comment: `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSinkProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.RateStreamProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.TextSocketSourceProvider
`

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat this is required for avro datasource, as it is not available in that file so it is not able to find avro source.

Comment: I edited the pom.xml as your suggestion, but there's still no `org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat` in the file `META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.source.DataSourceRegister` which unziped from newly build jar

Comment: Is this issue fixed ?

Comment: sorry for late response, the  issue hasn't been resolved yet